# Button Command not triggered WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

While this should work, it doesn't
I have in one of my user controls the following code:

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="45" DataContext="{Binding BottomOptions}" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstOptions, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Black"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button CommandParameter="{Binding OptionName, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.BottomOptionSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FF090909">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image, Mode=OneWay}" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OptionName, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" FontFamily="{Binding DataContext.BasicFont, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type base:BaseApplication}}}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This works for all of the items in the collection other than the last one.
In the last one, I have to click only the top of the button in order for the command to be triggered, if I click the middle or bottom of the button, nothing happens.
This is vary strange since there is no difference in the code between the first buttons and the last one.

Please help

As per the comments I am adding the code that is in the VM:

```
public class MainDataContext : Observables
{
    public BottomOption OptionsList { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand BottomOptionSelected { get; set; }

    public MainDataContext()
    {
        BottomOptionSelected = new DelegateCommand(SelectBottomOption);
        OptionsList = new OptionsList();
        OptionsList.FirstOptions = new ObservableCollection<BottomOption>();
        OptionsList.FirstOptions.Add(new BottomOption() { OptionName = "First", Image = @"C:\FirstImage.png", BackgroundColor = Brushes.Gray });
        OptionsList.FirstOptions.Add(new BottomOption() { OptionName = "Second", Image = @"C:\SecondImage.png", BackgroundColor = Brushes.Gray });
        OptionsList.FirstOptions.Add(new BottomOption() { OptionName = "Third", Image = @"C:\ThirdImage.png", BackgroundColor = Brushes.Gray });
        OptionsList.FirstOptions.Add(new BottomOption() { OptionName = "Forth", Image = @"C:\ForthImage.png", BackgroundColor = Brushes.Gray });
        OptionsList.FirstOptions.Add(new BottomOption() { OptionName = "Fifth", Image = @"C:\FifthImage.png", BackgroundColor = Brushes.Gray });
    }

    protected virtual void SelectBottomOption(object aObject)
    {
        // Put a break point here and check if it gets here when clicking the bottom of the fifth option 
    }
}

public class BottomOption : Observables
{
    public ObservableCollection<BottomOption> FirstOptions { get; set; }
}

public class BottomOption : Observables
{
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you exceeding any borders? So that all of your Buttons fit  - for example in a grid - but only the last one will be "cut off"?

Comment: Since the content is in a UniformGrid it sets the size according to the container so the buttons are all displayed and not behind anything + this ItemsControl is inside a DockPanel so nothing can overlap it

Comment: Could you provide an example of a `FirstOptions` list? Could you try [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and check which control takes the button click?

Comment: FirstOptions is an ObservableCollection of a class that contains several properties, the ones you see are:
Image - a string pointing to a png file
OptionName - a simple string
BackgroundColor - a Brush (in this case the selected option is in a different color) (Yes, I know there is the option of using ListBox but that is not the question here)

Comment: I'm not suggesting a ListBox. Could you provide a *code example* of that ObservableCollection? If someone is going to reproduce this issue, it would help very much if they don't have to write a bunch of code just to get your current code working. Did you try Snoop?

Comment: I agree, your ViewModel would be appreciable to try to reproduce it. Plus Snoop is a good tool to understand what happen in the UI.

Comment: why are you binding to `DataContext.Command` instead of just `Command`?

Comment: I am binding Datacontext.Command since the command is not on the class of the current data context but on a relative source above it

Comment: For an unknown reason it started working again.
Thank you for everyone that tried to help

Comment: Should be deleted - there is nothing in this question that is useful to someone else seeking help.